# How close can pex tubing be to a boiler?

Tags: plumbing, boiler, pex, water-circulating-heating

I am adding radiators to my 2-pipe central heating (UK). The whole piping is copper 22mm and microbore, and I'm extending it with 15mm pex barrier pipe graded for central heating.

I know that the first bit of pipes connected to the boiler must be copper, which is the case.

However, I couldn't find whether there is a minimum distance between the boiler and plastic pipes merely passing near to it, **without being directly connected to it**.

Is there such a thing?

Any other comment on what I'm trying to do is welcome

Comment: I would have to think the exposed part of the boiler is an exterior tank and not scalding hot; it might be warm, but I would expect it to only be about the temperature of the exterior of a hot water heater. How hot is the surface?

Comment: The boiler has casing, so it can get just warm when running.